# Calculating MOSFET gate current with \$Q_\text{total} = I_\text{gate} \cdot t\$

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, gate-driving, powermosfet

Hi I am using the MOSFET IRFP4368. I want to use the equation 
$$
Q_\text{total} = I_\text{gate} \cdot t 
$$
to calculate the required gate current of my MOSFET driver. I have my total \$Q_\text{total}\$ from the data sheet. I am not sure what \$t\$ would be in this instance. Is it the \$t_\text{rise}\$ given in the data sheet? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, t_rise or t_fall according to the operation and implementation of logic function. Though the Igate and t are actually dependent on each other.

Comment: t is however long you want Igate to exist for.

Comment: My data sheet is given a trise of 250ns, so therefore, Ig =Qg/250ns. Can I design for 0.5us or even 1us?